# Conditional default values in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using MS Access 2007. I have a form with several phone number fields (cell, home, work, primary*). The data source for all of these fields comes from a Customers table.

Basically, what I am trying to do is establish a set of default values for the primary* field. I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
If [cell] <> Null:
    primary* = [cell]

elif [cell] Is Null and [home] <> Null:
    primary* = [home]

elif [cell] Is Null and [home] is Null and [work] <> Null:
    primary* = [work]
```

I know this isn't very logical code, but I hope you can see what I'm trying to do here. I just want the primary* field to default to the cell number if there is one, then the home number if there is no cell, and finally the work number if it's the only one available.

Is there a way to do this with the Properties panel in Access?

Comment: You don't want to duplicate the data (i.e., copying the same phone number into the default field). Instead, you want to have a field whose purpose is to identify which number is the default. The simplest way to do this is with an integer field and use an option group to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

The default value property for a data control is evaluated/applied at the instant a new record is started.  It's probably obvious that happens before the new record has been INSERTed into the table.  Perhaps less obviously, it happens before the user has entered **any** data into the new record.  So even if it were possible to have the default value based on another field value ... the other fields would be Null at that point, unless they also had a default value assigned.

In a different situation you might consider the form's before insert event to assign whichever control value you want to the target control.  However, that's not such a great fit if you want the user to change the default primary value before the record is saved.

Think I might fall back to using the after update events on the individual phone number controls.  So for [cell] after update, you could use:

```
If IsNull(Me.primary) Then
    Me.primary = Me.cell
End If
```

And similar for the others.

After the user or the code has assigned a value to Me.primary, it will be left unchanged unless the user changes it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind your control being read only, you could simply use a expression as your source control. Something like this :

```
=iif(IsNull(Cell);iif(IsNull(Home);Work;Home);Cell)
```

If you want the control to be editable, you'll need to dynamically change the control source in the code behind on the onActivate event I guess (I haven't tested that).